# HTML5 - What is making this code get the country instead of city?

Tags: html, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

What is making the following code get the country and not the city, and how can I change it to get the city instead of country?

```
function get_visitor_country() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){ 
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
                    if (results[1]) {
                        var country = results[results.length-1].formatted_address;
                        $("#location-detection .location-name").html(country);
                        $("#geolocation-worked").css("display", "block");
                        $("#no-geolocation").css("display", "none");

                        $geolocation_fix.hide().css({ height : 0 });

                        init_geolocation_switch();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The script is also loading http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false at the end of the file, if that might be affecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script currently is not getting anything special(like a city or a country) , it gets something out of the results.

To get the city search inside the results for an entry with **types** set to `["locality", "political"]`

When you found it you got the city.

---

Creation of an object labeled with addressTypes for convenient access:

```
var components={};
jQuery.each(results,function(i,v){
  components[jQuery.camelCase(v.types.join('-'))]=v;
})

//test it
alert((components.localityPolitical)
        ? components.localityPolitical.formatted_address
        : 'n/a');
```

See: [**Address Component Types**](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html#GeocodingAddressTypes)